# Angular nested-scopes and nested-views retaining model data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model, scope, nested

I currently have an application with a rather complex wizard to create a data record. The wizard consists of 3 steps, each associated with a nested view and a controller. Only the data record itself is shared among all three scopes and each controller contributes additional data to the main record.
But they also have scope specific data, that will be used to render additional fields which are only relevant to that nested scope.

I want to be able to go back and forth between the wizard steps but currently it looks like the nested scopes get discarded as soon as I move on to another nested view. I looked up the scope lifecycle in the developer guide: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle
But I does not really tell me how the scope lifecycle applies to nested scopes and how I can prevent these scopes from being discarded. Of course I could move all the data of the nested scopes into the parent scope, but to me that would just feel like a workaround, because actually that data is only relevant to the individual scopes.

I'll try to give a short example:

```
angular.module('app').controller('ParentCtrl', function ($scope) {
  ...
  $scope.dataRecord = {};
}
angular.module('app').controller('Child1Ctrl', function ($scope) {
  ...
  $scope.dataRecord.test = 'a';
  $scope.childScope1SpecificData = '123';
}
angular.module('app').controller('Child2Ctrl', function ($scope) {
  ...
  $scope.dataRecord.test2 = 'b';
  $scope.childScope2SpecificData = '456';
}
```

When I now switch back and forth between the two childscopes, the dataRecord will be adjusted properly, but changes to childScope1SpecificData (via an input field from the template) will be discarded as soon as I switch to Child2Ctrl and back.

Is there a way to persist this data which switching the scope or is it meant to be discarded and I am simply using it wrong?

Thanks

EDIT:
Ok I looked into the factory approach. Maybe to make it more plastic: The additional data, that belongs to each child scope, is a fileuploader with its associated upload queue. Only in a later validation step these pictures actually become part of the datarecord, but until then I don't want the uploaded images to get lost upon switching views.
So what I could do is to externalize the whole fileupload logic into a factory that returns fileuploaders associated to IDs. Whenever a child scope requests the same id the factory will return the same fileuploader. Different Ids will return different uploaders or new ones. That would pretty much solve the problem but would also mean that the data never gets discarded at all unless I really close the browser, because the factory now is absolutely independent of any scope. Since I only want to retain the data in the context of that wizard, I want the data to be discarded, as soon as I leave the wizard.
So after having looked into these other approaches, it seems like I have to go with the original idea: I have to attach the uploaders to the parent scope. So they will continue to exist when switching to other child views, but they will also be discarded as soon as I leave the wizard.

I hope that was correctly summarized

Comment: When you switch to a controller, a new instance is created and all the local changes within that scope are renewed/reinitialized. However, if you want to retain data while switching, use parent scope, $rootScope, or a factory.

Comment: Factory would be great for this.

Comment: I edited my original post regarding your factory ideas

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 'controller as' syntax, you can use this variant.

```
angular.module('app').controller('ParentCtrl', function ($scope) {
  ...
  $scope.dataRecord = {};
}
angular.module('app').controller('Child1Ctrl', function ($scope) {
  ...
  $scope.ParentCtrl.dataRecord.test = 'a';
  $scope.ParentCtrl.childScope1SpecificData = '123';
}
angular.module('app').controller('Child2Ctrl', function ($scope) {
  ...
  $scope.ParentCtrl.dataRecord.test2 = 'b';
  $scope.ParentCtrl.childScope2SpecificData = '456';
}
```

So, you are changing ParentCtrl object in you parent scope, not for every instance.
Sorry, if it was no understandable

Comment: But that again means that I attach the data to the parent scope right? That's what I consider a workaround, because the data is actually not relevant for the parent. I would only attach it to the parent, so that it does not get discarded.